# Can @@Error be non-Zero on a successful insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure how to make this happen. We're debugging an issue and we need to know if it's possible for @@Error to be non-zero if the insert succeeds. We have a stored procedure that exits if @Error <> 0. And if we knew the answer to this, that would help. Anyone know?

The code is below. We want to know if it's possible to get to the goto statement if the insert succeeded.

```
    -- This happened
    insert into Workflow
    (SubID, ProcessID, LineID, ReadTime)
    values
    (@sub_id, @proc_id, @line_id, @read_time)

    set @error = @@Error
    set @insertedWorkflowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    if @error <> 0 
    begin
        set @error_desc = 'insert into tw_workflow'
        goto ERROR_EXIT
    end

    -- This didn't happen
    INSERT INTO Master.WorkflowEventProcessing (WorkflowId, SubId, ReadTime, ProcessId, LineId) VALUES (@insertedWorkflowId, @sub_id, @read_time, @proc_id, @line_id)
    INSERT INTO Master.ProcessLogging (ProcessCode, WorkflowId, SubId, EventTime) VALUES (10, @insertedWorkflowId, @sub_id, GETDATE())
```

**EDIT**

Maybe a better way to say what's wrong is this: The first insert happened but the last two didn't. How is that possible? Maybe the last two inserts simply just failed?

Comment: Can you post the code in question? Also, are there triggers defined on the table you insert into?

Comment: And yes, there is a trigger on the table.

Comment: By the way, the trigger is for update and delete, not an insert. So the trigger shouldn't affect this.

Comment: From MSDN: [When Microsoft® SQL Server™ completes the execution of a Transact-SQL statement, @@ERROR is set to 0 if the statement executed successfully. If an error occurs, an error message is returned. @@ERROR returns the number of the error message until another Transact-SQL statement is executed. You can view the text associated with an @@ERROR error number in the sysmessages system table.]  -  That means the above goto statement can't be reached if the insert was successful (and no trigger fired).

Comment: Is it possible that the code at ERROR_EXIT is reached from some other place? Also, what is the exact behavior you are concerned about?

Comment: We have a situation where the first insert happened, but the last two didn't. We're trying to figure out how that happened.

Comment: You should not be trapping errors this way anyway. You should be using a try catch block and transactions so that all records are rolled back if any are rolled back. I would suspect that your other inserts failed but with no transaction the whole thing did not get rolled back. Do you know the data that was sent in when it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this insert succeeds then there will be a non-zero [@@rowcount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) since you're simply using `values` (rather than a `select...where` which could "successfully" insert 0 rows).  You could use this to write some debug checks in there, or just include it as part of the routine for good.

```
insert into Workflow
(SubID, ProcessID, LineID, ReadTime)
values
(@sub_id, @proc_id, @line_id, @read_time)

if @@rowcount = 0 or @@error <> 0 -- Problems!
```

**UPDATE**

If a trigger fires on insert, an error in the trigger with severity of:

- < 10: will run without a problem, @@error = 0
- between 11 and 16: insert **will succeed, @@error != 0**
- 17, 18: insert will succeed, execution will halt
- 19 (with log): insert will succeed, execution will halt
- > 20 (with log): insert will **not** succeed, execution will halt

I arrived at this by adding a trigger to the workflow table and testing various values for severity, so I can't readily say this would be the exact case in all environments:

```
alter trigger workflowtrig on workflow after insert as begin
    raiserror(13032, 20, 1) with log -- with log is necessary for severity > 18
end
```

**Soooo**, after that, we have somewhat of an answer to this question:

> Can @@Error be non-Zero on a successful insert?

**Yes...BUT**, I'm not sure if there is another chain of events that could lead to this, and I'm not creative enough to put together the tests to prove such.  Hopefully someone else knows for sure.

I know this all isn't a great answer, but it's too big for a comment, and I thought it might help!

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. We're trying to figure out a problem that already occurred. We know there are ways to make this better and fix it.

Comment: +1 for some good info. This can't happen in my case because the trigger is only for update and delete. Out of curiosity, where did you find that information?

Comment: Triggers have xact abort on implicitly so the behaviour with raiserror will be different from what happens with other errors.

Comment: Even though I still don't know how my issue could have happened, this does a good job answering the overall question that @@Error can indeed be non-zero on a successful insert. Thanks!

Comment: Please update us if/when you find what the cause was. This is pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

According to the T-SQL [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx), this should not be possible. You could also wrap this in a try / catch, to attempt to catch most errors.

You might want to also consider the possibility that SCOPE_IDENTITY() is not returning the correct value, or the value you think it is. If you have FKs on the Master.WorkflowEventProcessing and Master.ProcessLogging tables, you could get a FK error attempting to insert into those tables because the value returned from SCOPE_IDENTITY is not correct.

Comment: +1 for the good point about the possibility that SCOPE_IDENTITY() could cause the problem here. However, I think Tim shows, below, that it is possible to have an insert succeed with a non-zero @@Error.

Comment: While there is a problem with scope_identity(), it is unlikely to cause any issue here. See http://sqlity.net/en/351/identity-crisis/ for details of how to work around this bug. But again, I don't think this is the problem here.